# Python function return is none

Tags: python

I have a problem in my project. In my program I have the availability to choose more files if I want. The Problem is, that the `return choosen_files` has the list of the files but choosen_files which calls the more_files() method is none.

Do you have any suggestion?

Here is my code

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog as fd
def get_files(path):

    root = tk.Tk()
    root.withdraw()
    files = fd.askopenfilenames(
        parent=root, title='Choose all files you want', initialdir=path)
    return list(files)


def more_files(choosen_files, path):
    print("choosen files:")
    [print(file) for file in choosen_files]

    wantMoreFiles = input(
            "Do you want to choose more files? [(1) yes, (2) no]").lower()
    if wantMoreFiles in ['1', 'y', 'yes']:
        new_files = get_files(path)
        choosen_files.extend(new_files)
        more_files(choosen_files, path)

    else:
        return choosen_files
               #this has the correct list

files = ['path/file1']
path = 'path'

choosen_files = more_files(files, path)
#this is none
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't return anything on the last line.
Just return more_files(files, path)

Comment: That works for me. Thank you! But can you explain, why a return is needed there? Because when I go into the first if-statement I call the method again. But when I go into the else part, it returns the file list. But why I need than a return in the first condition?

Comment: It is the return value that brings in the choosen_files parameter when you do your recursive call. A python function that doesn't explicitly return anything will return None. So then your next call to more_files will have the first parameter being None.